# How to add description to a cog?

Tags: python, discord.py

This might be a stupid question but... How do I add description to cogs??

Currently I'm making a custom help command for my bot and since it's still in development and I'll be surelly adding more cogs to it, it would make my life way easier to just have cog descriptions!

In the discord.py documentation the object cog has the attribute description which does the following:

[image]

and I just couldn't make sense of that! I did some research but I couldn't find any examples of cog descriptions.

So here is a simple cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Funny(commands.cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def funnyImage(ctx):
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('memes/funnyImage.png'))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Imagens(bot))
```

How would I add a description to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick look at the documentation and found the following:

[image: Screenshot from discord.py]

I can't test it right now but it looks like you have to pass it to the class definition directly, e.g. `class MyCog(commands.Cog, description="Hello"):`